# Test for missing user input, and stop or delay a Google script from running

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below Google script running in a Google sheet.

```
function sendNotification(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var emailAdd = "email@yourdomain.com";
  if(event.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("G") > -1 && sheet.getRange("G" + row).getDisplayValue() > 999 && emailAdd.length > 1)
  {
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
  var bodyHTML,o,sendTO,subject;//Declare variables without assigning a value
o = {};//Create an empty object
bodyHTML = "There has been a new allocation request from " + rowVals.name + " in the " + rowVals.team + " team.<br \> <br \> " 
       + "<table border = \"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><th>Issuing Depot</th><th>Delivery Date</th><th>Case Quantity</th></tr><tr><td>"+rowVals.depot+"</td><td>"+rowVals.date+"</td><td>"+rowVals.quantity+"</td></tr></table>" 
       + "<br \>To view the full details of the request, use the link below.<br \> <br \>" + 
       "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com\">Allocation Requests</a>"
       +"<br \> <br \><i>This is an automated email. Please do not reply to it.<\i>";
o.htmlBody = bodyHTML;//Add the HTML to the object with a property name of htmlBody
o.from = aliases[0]; //Add the from option to the object
sendTO = "email@yourdomain.com";
subject = "Allocation Request - " + rowVals.quantity + " cases on " + rowVals.date,
GmailApp.sendEmail(sendTO,subject,"",o);//Leave the third parameter as an empty string because the htmlBody advanced parameter is set in the object.  
    };
  }

  function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("G" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  var nameCell = sheet.getRange("B" + cellRow);
  var name = nameCell.getDisplayValue();
  var teamCell = sheet.getRange("C" + cellRow);
  var team = teamCell.getDisplayValue();
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant,
    name: name,
    team: team
  } }
```

It works fine, but if the person who fills out the spreadsheet doesn't fill out the columns in ascending order, the email that gets sent misses out information.
Is there a way to delay the running of the script until the row (columns B,C,D,E,F & G) has been completed? I've looked at `utilities.sleep` but not sure where to put it in the script. When I've tried to do so, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Test the return object for missing values.  The way that the following code does this is to convert the object to an array, and then get the length of the array.  There should be 4 elements in the array.  If the value of any of the variables that go into the object is undefined, then that element will be missing, and therefore the array will have fewer than 4 elements.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);//Returns an object
  var testArray = JSON.stringify(o).split(",");//Convert object to an array

  Logger.log('length: ' + testArray.length)

  if (testArray.length !== 4) {//Object must have 4 elements
    Browser.msgBox('There is missing data!');
    return;  //quit
  }
}

function getActiveRowValues() {
  var depot = 'something';
  var date;//For testing purposes - leave this as undefined
  var name = 'the name';
  var team = 'team is';

  var o = {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    name: name,
    team: team
  }

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
  return o;
}
```

You could improve upon this by highlighting cells with missing data, or determining exactly which piece of data is missing and informing the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer that you want to hear.  But I'm not familiar with any trigger that's associated to specific cells.  The question has come up many times and the closest we have is the on edit event.  I suppose you could check on each on edit to see if the appropriate cells contained appropriate data.  Personally, I would prefer a dialog or sidebar for this situation and then I could have all of the power of Javascript in an html environment to help with the form submission process and in the end I'd probably just put a send button there.

Answer (score 0):

I carried on playing around with `utilities.sleep` and have now got it to work as shown below.

```
function sendNotification(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  if(event.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("G") > -1 && sheet.getRange("G" + row).getDisplayValue() > 999)
  {
  Utilities.sleep(1200000)  
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
  var bodyHTML,o,sendTO,subject;//Declare variables without assigning a value
o = {};//Create an empty object
bodyHTML = "There has been a new allocation request from " + rowVals.name + " in the " + rowVals.team + " team.<br \> <br \> " 
       + "<table border = \"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><th>Issuing Depot</th><th>Delivery Date</th><th>Case Quantity</th></tr><tr><td>"+rowVals.depot+"</td><td>"+rowVals.date+"</td><td>"+rowVals.quantity+"</td></tr></table>" 
       + "<br \>To view the full details of the request, use the link below.<br \> <br \>" + 
       "<a href=\"https://docs.google.com\">Allocation Requests</a>"
       +"<br \> <br \><i>This is an automated email. Please do not reply to it.<\i>";
o.htmlBody = bodyHTML;//Add the HTML to the object with a property name of htmlBody
o.from = aliases[0]; //Add the from option to the object
sendTO = "email@yourdomain.com";
subject = "Allocation Request - " + rowVals.quantity + " cases on " + rowVals.date,

GmailApp.sendEmail(sendTO,subject,"",o);//Leave the third parameter as an empty string because the htmlBody advanced parameter is set in the object.  
    };
  }

  function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("G" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  var nameCell = sheet.getRange("B" + cellRow);
  var name = nameCell.getDisplayValue();
  var teamCell = sheet.getRange("C" + cellRow);
  var team = teamCell.getDisplayValue();
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant,
    name: name,
    team: team
  } }
```

It now delays the script from running for 1 minute, allowing time for the remaining cells to be completed before the script pull data from them.